# Compare char to string in Elm

Tags: elm

I'd like to loop through the characters of a string and see if each is contained in another string. However, String.toList returns a list of Chars, not Strings, which isn't allowed by the String.contains function. Passing the Char to toString doesn't help, is there another way to achieve this goal, or do I just need another approach altogether?

```
> String.contains (toString 'a') "asdf"
False : Bool
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [String.fromChar](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/4.0.5/String#fromChar) to convert a character to string.

```elm
String.fromChar 'a' -- "a"
String.contains (String.fromChar 'a') "asdf" -- True
```

Answer (score 1):

Use lists of characters directly:

```
> standard  = String.toList "asdf"
['a','s','d','f'] : List Char

> candidateGood = String.toList "asd"
['a','s','d'] : List Char

> candidateBad = String.toList "abc"
['a','b','c'] : List Char

> List.all (\x -> List.member x standard) candidateGood
True : Bool

> List.all (\x -> List.member x standard) candidateBad
False : Bool
```